# Problem deploying with capistrano. I can't restart puma with deploy user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, digital-ocean, capistrano3

I'm doing my first deployment in digital ocean. And almost at the end, capistrano raises a problem it says:

[image]

- Running /usr/bin/env sudo /bin/systemctl restart puma_web_app_production as deploy@host
- Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.7.3" ; /usr/bin/env sudo /bin/systemctl restart puma_web_app_production )
- sudo:a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper

I'm running it with a deploy user. I suppose that the problem is the user is not root. But how can I make it work with this user? where can I configure the user that runs this task?

Thanks a lot.